# get the process name from remote machine

Tags: linux, bash, shell, operating-system

How do I get the name of a process from a remote machine without ssh.

I have to get the name of the process without doing ssh or any other such utility.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `without doing ssh or any other such utility` by guess?

Comment: you'd better tell us, what tool you can use. what process name you want to check, and what services are running on the remote machine. with your current question, the answer would be writing email to your remote-server adm, letting him check for you.

Comment: You do understand that some communication tool must be used, don't you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it very quickly using netcat `nc`

On the remote server run this command:

```
while $(true); do ps -eaf | nc -l 1234; done
```

This uses netcat to send the output of ps to port 1234.  It is in a loop so that it will work more than once.

Then from your local you just have to run this command:

```
nc my_server 1234
```

And you will get a list of all the processes.  If you don't have nc on the client you can just use telnet:

```
telnet my_server 1234
```